# Cannot update GITHUB_PATH on self-hosted windows github action-runner

Tags: windows, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I have following workflow

```
name: Test set path
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  test-cross-aws:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, '${{ matrix.platform.os }}', x64, '${{ matrix.platform.label }}']
    #runs-on: windows-latest   
    strategy:
      matrix:
        platform: [{ os: windows, label: wix-aws-windows-test }]
    steps:
      - name: create fake batchfile
        if: always()
        run: |
           mkdir testfolder
           echo "@echo off" | Out-File -FilePath testfolder/testbatch.bat -Encoding utf8
           echo "echo SOMETHING" | Out-File -FilePath testfolder/testbatch.bat -Encoding utf8           

      - name: add path
        if: always()
        run: echo "$pwd\testfolder;" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_PATH -Encoding utf8 -Append

      - name: run custom binary with path
        if: always()
        run: testbatch.bat
```

It works ok on regular github action windows runner.
But it fails on self-hosted github runner built from this [image](https://github.com/philips-labs/terraform-aws-github-runner/tree/main/images/windows-core-2022)
The error is

```
testbatch.bat : The term 'testbatch.bat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\actions-runner\_work\_temp\744d9b45-8f99-4db5-ba7d-b95aad4dde97.ps1:2 char:1
+ testbatch.bat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (testbatch.bat:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Github runner version is 2.303.0
Windows i use is Windows 2022 datacenter.

Comment: Does it run by specifying its full path i.e. `testfolder/testbatch.bat`?

Comment: Looks like you have already created an issue on that image repo (https://github.com/philips-labs/terraform-aws-github-runner/issues/3095).

Comment: What version of the runner are you using? Does it support the new syntax? Have you tried the old `::add-path` syntax?

Comment: Try changing `echo $pwd/path" |` to simply `"$pwd/path;" |`, no need to echo here when simply piping a string to the file. Also, it looks like the script should be using PowerShell core, in which case you can use the simplified notation: `"$pwd/file" >> $env:GITHUB_PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for replies. 1. Github runner version is 2.303.0. 2. Yes ive tried old version with add-path, not working. 3. Ive tried various combinations of sytax, nothing worked so far. I guess its something with how instance starts the github agent.

Comment: In your script you have a `;` after your path, that's not what you want. Did you try my workflow below verbatim?

Comment: Have you configured the debug variables and extracted the runner logs from the agent to see whether there are any read/write issues?

Comment: yes. There are no read/write issues. Ive started local instance of windows 2022 server on my computer. It executes this workflow without error.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're running an [outdated version of the GitHub Runner that doesn't support the new syntax to add variables to the path](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/).

> If you are using self-hosted runners make sure they are updated to version 2.273.1 or greater.

I just ran this workflow (slightly simplified further) without failure on a self-hosted agent on Windows 11 Pro:

```
name: Test set path
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: [self-hosted]

    steps:
      - run: |
           mkdir testfolder -force | out-null
           echo "@echo off" > testfolder/testbatch.bat
           echo "echo SOMETHING" >> testfolder/testbatch.bat
      - run: |
            "$pwd\testfolder" >> $env:GITHUB_PATH
      - run: |
            & testbatch.bat
```

Which succeeded without any problems:

[image]

To check the contents of the `$env:GITHUB_PATH` simply write its content to the console:

```
gc $env:GITHUB_PATH | write-output
```

The *magic* `GITHUB_` environment variables point to a temporary file which is read by the runner after the step has finished. The environment variable provides us a way from knowing the name of the file without having to know the name of the file.

Comment: Thats awesome. How did you build the image? Can you share source for your packer project may be?

Comment: I just installed the runner manually.

Comment: The most recent images for the hosted runner are now here: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/tree/main/images%2Fwin

Comment: Thats no fun:) manually yes everything runs, i suppose because it runs under your username as regular app. It breaks down when it started automatically in aws.

Comment: Try running my above workflow and see if it works. ☝️ There is no reason running it as a service shouldn't work here. But that information is an important addition. Try writing `$env:PATH` to the console to see if there is any funny business in the path.

Comment: I reconfigured my runner to run as a service and that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution is to reinstall the self-hosted runner as a user and make sure this user has the specific permissions you need.
the default mode for self-hosted runners when you run the script is to be installed as a network service which might not have all permissions.
you can check this by running `whoami` from your action to make sure.